# Video not playing - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-android-player

I'm using Xamarin Android Player emulator to test the app I'm developing. The emulator doesn't play video at all. There's a black screen in place of the videoview.

I've written very simple code just to test the video playback. The code is below:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.video);

            videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);

            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");

            videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);

            videoView.Start();
        }
```

Is it because the emulator doesn't support video playback or for some other reason? I have INTERNET permission checked off in the android manifest. Which other emulator can I test it on?

Comment: Have you attempted to load an external webpage in your test app?

Comment: No I haven't. Do I need to do that?

Comment: Doing that would rule out a connection problem with your emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it definitely works. You can try it on GenyMotion Emulator.